# Knockoutjs Unable to parse bindings. Message: SyntaxError: Unexpected token };

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/fustic/NpK3K/5/). 
I simplified it as much as i could, but i still can't understand where i'm wrong.
Please help me ))

P.S stackoverflow require a code, not just link to jsfiddle, so this is it:
html:

```
<form action="" method="GET" data-bind="FacebookContacts">
    <table class="importContacts table import">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Photo</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Login</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: contacts">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text:FullName"></span>
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>​
```

javascript:

```
var FacebookContactsViewModel = function () {
        var _self = this;
        _self.FacebookContacts = ko.observable();
        _self.GetData = function() {
            var localData=ko.mapping.fromJS(JSON.parse(contacts));
            _self.FacebookContacts(localData);
            ko.applyBindings(_self);
        };
    _self.GetData();
};
var contacts='{"contacts":[{"FullName":"Petr Perelygin"}]}';
var vm = new FacebookContactsViewModel();​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at here and make your code more simpler and easier to read:

http://jsfiddle.net/NpK3K/24/

The problem was that you are putting an object into the `"FacebookContacts"` property and not an Array. So you should use the `"with"` binding extension at the first place for root element to change the datacontext for nested elements.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you!! helped the `with` binding - i just missed it ((.. You version looks better - i agree, but that structure i need because of application, of course there just much more staff and i simplified it just for example.. But anyway - thank you!!

Comment: Don't worry man. Knockoutjs is fantastic but somehow complicated. I missed a lot too! ;D Cheers.